# Does this component pattern work in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, design-patterns, xna

Is it possible to use this pattern in C#?
http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html

Is it limited to c++ with control over pointers and such?
Are there any similar patterns to develop around?
I know XNA uses somewhat of a component pattern but I think they are different in how they are implelemted, and used.

edit: I have tried implementing it but since I don't know pointers in c++, I dont know how to do with * and &, and think that they may be the key to the whole pattern.

Comment: You don't need pointers to do something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see at the end of that article XNA already implements that pattern out of the box:

"* Microsoft’s XNA game framework comes with a core Game class. It owns a collection of GameComponent objects. Where our example uses components at the individual game entity level, XNA implements the pattern at the level of the main game object itself, but the purpose is the same."

Comment: I guess it answers my question, but I cant see how the actual implementation works in XNA, which is a little part of what I was looking for. Will check as answer unless anything more useful comes.

Comment: Well, the implementation in that article is really not specific to C++. 

You can replace the pointers with plain references in c# and you can pretty much translate it as is. There is not a lot to it. So with XNA you have two options, you can implement it yourself (which you can do based on that article) or you can leverage the built-in implementation of GameComponent.